# How to pass object from function to oncreate method in android

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I have the following code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button_search.setOnClickListener {
            val search = editText_user_search.text.toString()
            fetchJson(search)
            val intent = Intent(this, WeatherForecast::class.java)
        }

    }
}

private fun fetchJson(userSearch: String){
    println("Attempting to fetch JSON")

    val url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$userSearch&appid=MY_API_KEY"

    //val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"
    println("the url is $url")
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response){
            val body = response.body?.string()

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val weatherinfo: WeatherInfo = gson.fromJson(body, WeatherInfo::class.java)


        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed to execute request.")
        }
    })
}
```

The idea is to take a user input (a city), do a get request (to get weather info about that city), use gson to turn it into a object then access fields of that object to put it onto a intent to pass to a new activity.

The problem here is that the object I want to access in onCreate, weatherInfo, is created during the function onResponse function inside the fetchJson function.

What is the best way to pass this information so I can add to my intent the following line `intent.putStringExtra("City", weatherInfo.name)` so I can access it on another activity.

If there is a best practise for handling this situation I would be grateful to know!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I just neutralized the post by upvote for now since i didn't find why somebody downvoted. So do you like to use coroutines here? If yes lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use suspendCoroutine, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html

```
private fun fetchJson(userSearch: String): WeatherInfo? = suspendCoroutine<WeatherInfo?> { cont ->
    println("Attempting to fetch JSON")

    val url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$userSearch&appid=MY_API_KEY"

    //val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"
    println("the url is $url")
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response){
            val body = response.body?.string()

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val weatherinfo: WeatherInfo = gson.fromJson(body, WeatherInfo::class.java)

            cont.resume(weatherinfo)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed to execute request.")
            cont.resume(null)
        }
    })
}
```

Now the fetchJson will return WeatherInfo object if call was succeed and null if onFailure() was called

**Edit1:** You can also use `Continuation.resumeWithException(e)` instead of resuming with null if you want to handle/propagate exception instead of Nulls.

**Edit2:** see https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/where-is-suspendcoroutine-supposed-to-be-used/11190/2 for more knowledge about this topic.